# Rails Migration: Determine what is being used as database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to set an `autoincrement` value for the Sqlite database I am currently using. In the future, I will be switching to Postgresql because I will be deploying to heroku and thus will want Postgresql local for development.

Until then, I'm using Sqlite. Is there a way I can write a migration such that it knows which database provider I'm using so that I can have two separate `execute` statements to set `autoincement`?

Comment: why not just use postgres now?  it's much, much easier than switching later.  If there's a good reason, then fine, but if it's 'just because i don't want to do it now' (which i say a lot)...then trust me, from experience, just do it now.

Comment: I use postgres for all of my projects. I was using a slower netbook to start the project off. I didn't want to have postgres running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling connection.adapter_name in your migration. It should return either: "PostgreSQL" or "SQLite".